# No playing sound on AR.js 

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, interactive, ar.js

I've been working Augmented Reality with AR.js for WebAR experiences & I need play sounds touching 3d objects on screen, but by now I can't, this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Reproducción de sonido en AR.js</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/2.2.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <script>
      function reproducirSonido() {
        var sonido = document.getElementById("sonido");
        sonido.play();
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      #marcador {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-top: -150px;
        margin-left: -150px;
        background-color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <a-marker
        preset="custom"
        type="pattern"
        url="https://cdn.glitch.global/847d4754-7230-4eb5-baeb-1626c2b619be/marker.patt?v=1681415242369"
      >
        <a-entity
          gltf-model="https://cdn.glitch.global/847d4754-7230-4eb5-baeb-1626c2b619be/tecla001.gltf?v=1681415241911"
          scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"
          position="0 0 0"
          rotation="0 45 0"
          onclick="reproducirSonido()"
        ></a-entity>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
    <audio
      id="sonido"
      src="https://cdn.glitch.global/847d4754-7230-4eb5-baeb-1626c2b619be/Funny_Scream.ogg?v=1681423344830"
    ></audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want, you can try the example from [Glitch website](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/relieved-nebula-meter?path=index.html%3A50%3A0) the pattern for this example is the classic AR black square.
Any suggestion or idea? 
Comment please.

Show & learn new experiences of WebAR with AR.js for anybody interested in this topic.